# Refactor checking that an item exist in an array

Tags: arrays, swift

In my code, I have to check an array contains a specific item or not.
Here is my code

```
If error.errors[0].peoples = .noteEntered {
  Print("something")
}
```

To learn better, can I ask you to show me how to do it in the better way, I think it's not good.

Many thanks

Comment: Please post the _real_ code, this snippet has multiple syntax errors.

Comment: if + `contains(where:)`, `if let` + `first(where:)` if you need the object.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
if error.errors.contains(where:{$0.peoples == .noteEntered}) {
   print("something")
}
```

If you need the item do

```
if let item = error.errors.first(where:{$0.peoples == .noteEntered}) {
   print(item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if error.errors[0].peoples.contains(.noteEntered) {
  print("something")
}
```

Comment: While the code-only answer may be a valid solution to the original problem, it's not helpful without providing any context. Explaining your code and why this answers the question will improve the quality of this answer.